# apt-get holds back upgrading from 20.04.1 to 20.04.2

Tags: apt, server, upgrade

On a Ubuntu server

`sudo apt-get upgrade` holds some packages (7) back from upgrading, so the system remains a 20.04.1.

With `sudo apt upgrade` all packages are installed and the system is now a 20.04.2.

Could you explain this behaior to me?

One problem is that with 20.04.2 I loose the abillity to scroll-up/down in the tty, which was different on the older kernel.

So the second question is how to get tty scrolling back (Shift PageUp/Down) within 20.04.2?

Thx a lot for any helpful advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a subtle one. `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt upgrade` differ slightly in semantics.  The plain 'apt' is designed to be human-friendly, and so it takes some actions not explicitly instructed to it: the notable one here is that it will install new packages.  `apt-get upgrade` doesn't: it will only upgrade packages that are already installed.  The equivalent for scripts would be `apt-get safe-upgrade`.

In other words, packages that are held back by `sudo apt-get upgrade` but not by `sudo apt upgrade` probably added new dependencies, which must be installed.

As for the scrollback problem, user535733 is incorrect: it is a kernel change.  More details can be found in [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/832304/) LWN article's comment section: in short, the ability to scroll back in a console is a mess for the kernel, and it was removed due to a perceived lack of need.  Without interested maintainers, kernel features tend to be removed: if you need it, I would suggest tweaking the login shell to one that supports scrollback, or else being willing to commit time and/or money to reintroducing the feature.

Comment: Good spot on the scrollback. The comment you refer to has been removed.

Comment: user535733: I only spotted it because I was pissed when I was no longer able to use it.

Comment: Staying with the 20.04.1 kernel version is another option if this feature is needed with all the drawbacks of older kernels. Do you use a login shell which can scrollback? Which? I tried tmux and screen the first time. But they have other problems. Normal history scrollback is not able out of the box. THX.